# call function when user clicks outside of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I call a function when the user clicks outside of a div?

The function is going to hide the div and some other elements on the page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple example:

***HTML***

```
<div id="target">
    Your div
    <span>A span</span>
    <div>
        Another child div
    </div>
</div>
```

***jQuery***

```
function hideDiv(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).is('#target') && !$(e.target).parents().is('#target')) {
        $('#target').hide();
    }
}
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
    hideDiv(e);
});
```

**[Working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/QStkd/502/)**

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the JQuery outside events plugin:

http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-outside-events-plugin/